# Calling controller method that contains Parameter for VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have this simple JS function implementation within my VF page:

```
<script>
 function toSend(){
   var myField;
   //Received myField value with some code//

   callingActionFunction(myField);

   //some more coding//
  }
</script>

<apex:actionFunction name="callingActionFunction" action="{!getFieldID}" immediate="true" rendered="false">
   <apex:param assignTo="{!agentObjID}" name="myField" value="myField"/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

My controller class:

```
public String agentObjID {get; set;}

public void getFieldID(){
  //SOQL to query based on the value: agentObjID 
  //but I am not receiving anything from my VF page.
}
```

But this above implementation is not seeming to work. All I am trying to do is: get the `myField` value in the VF's JS function and pass it to my controller class (I have get/set variable) and retrieve some record(s) based on that value. Can someone suggest me if I am doing it wrong or missing something simple or, my approach itself is invalid?

Comment: Is it because the actionFunction is not being rendered and can't be called as a result? What happens if you remove the rendered="false" from the apex:actionFunction?

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore PageReference on the method to view string parameters and values for a page
inside the method use

```
public PageReference getFieldID(){
  //SOQL to query based on the value: agentObjID 
}
```

Or

```
    <apex:actionFunction name="callingActionFunction" action="{!getFieldID}" immediate="true" rendered="false">
         <apex:param name="myField" value="myField"/>
     </apex:actionFunction>

        public PageReference getFieldID(){
          //SOQL to query based on the value: agentObjID 
          string agentObjID = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('myField');
        }
```